# Nested resources create Couldn't find Topic without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I wanna make an application which User can create a topic and others can make posts after that. I nested my resources in my routes.rb:

```
MyPedia2::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :users

    resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    resources :topics, only: [:show, :create, :destroy] 
    resources :posts
    resources :topics do

    resources :posts, only: [:create, :show, :new]

    end
```

In my topic show page , I want to show topic.title and sended Posts and post.form.html.erb.
Everything works accept when i create a post , I get mistake

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#create

Couldn't find Topic without an ID..
```

This is my posts_controller.rb:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user, only: :destroy

    def new
        @topic= Topic.find_by_id(params[:id])
        @post = @topic.posts.build(params[:post])
    end



    def show
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
    @posts = @topic.posts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end 

    def create
        @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
        @post = @topic.posts.build(params[:post])
        @post.topic  = @topic

        if @post.save
            flash[:success] = "Konu oluşturuldu!"
            redirect_to :back
        else
            render 'static_pages/home'
        end
    end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end
  private

    def correct_user
      @post = current_user.posts.find_by_id(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_path if @post.nil?
    end
end
```

and _post_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @new_post do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "yorumunuzu girin..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Gönder", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that should solve things for you.

First and foremost, your create action in the posts controller is a bit wrong - it should look something like this:

```
  def create
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = @topic.posts.build(params[:post])

    # This is unnecessary as you're already adding
    # the post to the topic with the build statement.
    # @post.topic  = @topic

    if @post.save
        flash[:success] = "Konu oluşturuldu!"
        redirect_to :back
    else
        render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
```

This controller action assumes that you're going to use a put request to a post resource that is nested in topics, so you'll have to clean up your routes.

You have routes to `posts#create` both nested and unnested.
If posts are ALWAYS supposed to be nested within a topic, which your controller logic is stating, then you should add this to the unnested posts resource:

```
resources :posts, except: [:new, :create]
```

and then change that `form_for` tag to this:

```
<%= form_for [@topic, @post] do |f| %>
```

This tells the form builder that you're using a nested resource and will use the correct url for the http request.

Also - it looks like you're using loading all of your topics using `Topic.find(params[:id])`. This isn't going to work - you're in the posts controller, this is a post id. You should be loading posts with the id param like this: `Post.find(params[:id])` and then the topic like this: `topic = post.topic`